# Communication Manager that controls rate of asynchronous network messaging design

Tags: java, thread-safety, synchronized

I have a system that I need to access, and access rate to this system is 1 API call a second. However, I wish to provide access to it through a web interface that is asynchronous. I have a design that calls for a dedicated communications manager thread that collects messages into a queue, and transmits them one at a time, followed with a call back to the sender with the results of the message.

Is this a good approach? Do you see any obvious pitfalls in my code as it currently stands?

```
public class CommunicationManager implements Runnable
{
    private BlockingQueue<Message> message = new LinkedList<> ();

    private boolean shutdown = false;

    private Messenger messenger = new Messenger();

    public CommunicationManager() {}

    public void run()
    {
        long elapsed, start, diff;
        start = 0;

        while (!shutdown)
        {
            elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis();
            diff = elapsed - start;
            if (diff < 1000)
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000 - diff);
            }
            if (!message.isEmpty())
            {
                Message next = message.remove();
                next.getSender().recieve(messenger.send(next.getMessage()));
            }
            start = elapsed;
        }           
    }

    public synchronized void addMessage(Sender sender, String message)
    {
        this.message.add(new Message(sender, message));
    }

    public synchronized void shutdown()
    {
        this.shutdown = true;
    }
}
```

The hopeful result of this manager is that every loop, if a second hasn't passed since the start of the previous loop, it will sleep for the remaining time. Then it will check to see if the queue is empty. If the queue is not empty it will retrieve the next message in the queue, send the message and return the result to the sender's callback. Then the loop ends and it starts the loop again.

I used a BlockingQueue to avoid issues where someone is adding a message to the queue as I am removing the last message in the queue. I do not think the default Queue structure is thread safe, so I need some means to prevent this from occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was reinventing the wheel a bit here. What I really wanted to do can be done much more easily with a Java ScheduledExecutorService.

```
class CommunicationControl
{
   private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduluer = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

   public void startManager()
   {
      final CommunicationManager manager = new CommunicationManager();
      scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(manager, 10, 1, SECONDS);
   }

   public void stopManager()
   {
      while (manager.getMessageCount() > 0)
      {
          try
          {
              Thread.sleep(manager.getMessageCount() * 1000);
          } catch (InterruptedException e)
          {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
      scheduler.shutdown();
   }
}
```

A Reworking of the original class here:

```
class CommunicationManager implements Runnable
{
   private BlockingQueue<Message> message = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Message> (1000);
   private Messenger messenger = new Messenger();

   public CommunicationManager() {}

   public void run()
   {
      Message next = message.poll();
      if (next != null)
      {
         next.getSender().recieve(messenger.send(next.getMessage()));
      }
   }

   public void addMessage(Sender sender, String message)
   {
       try
       {
          while (!this.message.offer(new Message(sender, message), 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {}
       } catch (InterruptedException e)
       {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}
```

What this will do is first create an executor to handle how often my Communication Manager is run, which in this case is once a second after a delay of 10 seconds. Then once this happens every second the Run method of CommuncationManager will execute performing exactly one unit of work if available.

Other methods are free to add work to the CommunicationManager so long as there is queue space, if not they will block until space becomes available.

This also frees me to be able to build this into a framework such as Spring.